# Why executing npm --version in WSL2 as specific user resulting bad interpreter: no such file or directory?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, windows-10, wsl-2

I'm trying to check installed npm in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.

I run this command

```
npm --version
```

It resulted

```
-bash: /mnt/c/ProgramData/scoop/apps/nodejs/current/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But if I switch to root user, by executing below command:

```
sudo su
```

I can check npm version

```
root@LAPTOP:/home/user/folder/web/src# npm --version
6.14.4
root@LAPTOP:/home/user/folder/web/src#
```

Why when I execute using non root user, I can not run npm command. Seem like it's trying to mount from c drive mounting by wsl.

Comment: Feed /mnt/c/ProgramData/scoop/apps/nodejs/current/npm through `fromdos`.

Comment: @Roadowl what is feed? I execute thru dos/ps and wsl it's give me unknown command